# Pull docker image and upload to Azure App Service programmatically

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

We have a requirement, where we publish a docker image, and a client through an automation workflow tool such as Logic App pull down a docker image and upload it to an Azure App Service instance. Is #2, #3 achievable via some from of RESTFul API?

1. We publish an image into docker hub
2. Client runs a process to
   pull this image down via HTTP request
3. And upload it to an
   instance of an Azure app service via HTTP Request

I found this : https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image just unsure if this is useful in the sense where we need to deploy this image to an Azure App Service instance and let it run the image?

Answer (score 1):

You don't download an image from a container registry and upload it to App Service, you need to update the App Service configuration and App Service will pull the image.  You can do this using the Azure CLI:

```
az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name org/hello-app:1.0  --name demoforharry --resource-group demo
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest)

If you want to use HTTP, I guess that you can also use the Azure Management API.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I did exactly that for a learning excerise in docker and Azure App Service. I guess my question should be updated too " Can you update an App Service Configuration" via an API so that we can point it to a docker image

Comment: If you can do it using the Azure CLI, you can do it using the Azure Management REST API.